# Laravel-Store API data in database table

Tags: php, laravel, api, model-view-controller

Hi I am working on Laravel project where I need to call API and display its data in the dashboard and store the data into the database table as well for future needs.
I am able to get the data and pass it to view in the dashboard for display but unable to store it into a database table.
Below is the index function of my controller that fetch the data from API.

```
public function index()
  {
    $user = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')->json();
    return view('users')->with([
       'users' =>  $user
    ]);
}
```

Now I need help regarding storing data into database table. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simple handle is create "user" before return

```
public function index()
  {
    $user = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')->json();

    User::create([
            'name' => $user['name'],
            'email' => $user['email'],
            ...
        ]);

    return view('users')->with([
       'users' =>  $user
    ]);
}
```

More efficient way is use Laravel event:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events

Comment: 1.get Json (or make Json from response)
2.store Json im db.